# Typescript command line options reference

Tags: typescript, command-line, code-documentation

Is there a reference for all the TypeScript command line options? I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find any resource that is dedicated to documenting all those options; not even in the official Typescript Lang documentation site.

Comment: Do you mean for `tsc`? Did you try `tsc --help`, or read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html?

Comment: @jonrsharpe tsc --help is helpful, but not comprehensive. The explanations for each switch leaves out a lot of information. I suppose I could cross-reference with the tsconfig compiler options documentation, but I wish there was a page dedicated to using the tsc CLI. There is no indication that all the compiler options can be used verbatim for the CLI

Comment: A page like the one above, or are you looking for something different? It's unclear what you think is missing.